Is there a way to access session stored in redis in log configuration stage in rails?
I have a rails 7 web app, which uses redis, hiredis, redis-actionpack to store session data. We also use devise for auth. Now, I wish to use log tags to include user_id in every line the logger logs. Is there a way to do this without me having to call redis.get directly and Marshaling stuff out?
If we used cookie store - the default thing, shaking the cookie jar would work -
   # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
    config.log_tags = [:request_id, proc do |req|
      session_key = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key]
      session_data = req.cookie_jar.encrypted[session_key]
      if session_data.present?
        warden_data = session_data['warden.user.user.key']
        "user_id: #{warden_data[0][0]}" if warden_data.present?
      end
    end]

But I don't want to touch redis directly.
I have tried req.session.to_hash or req.session[:_csrf_token] etc to try and force it, but it doesn't stick. I always get an empty {} back, staring blankly!
How can I use any higher level function to access session data?

Instead of attempting to access the stored credentials directly (which is kind of smelly) try request.env['warden'].user&.id as warden injects itself as middleware into the request. https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/wiki/Users

@max warden hasn't initialised session at the point logger middleware is activated. In fact warden waits until ActionDispatch inits rack.session. So doesn't work.

Ah, I stand corrected. I guess it makes sense that you would want to put your logger as far up the middeware stack as possible. Would it be possible to declare your own logger class instead?

Yeah, that’s one option. I currently am using lograge, so it is coming in json data.
Another option is to use move_before on middleware to move cookie and redis store middlewares before rack logger.
Both approaches work.
